# Call php function from different class, namespace and file using include

Tags: php, function, namespaces

I am aware that this question is very similar if not exactly the same as a few others but I seem to have problems Calling the function even after following those advises. Thanks for your understanding.

I'm trying set the username with "setUserName" function from this file Calling the function from Another file as shown below. I seem to be missunderstanding how to call classes and namespaces.

```
namespace StructType;

use \WsdlToPhp\PackageBase\AbstractStructBase;

/**
 * This class stands for webExport StructType
 * @subpackage Structs
 */
class WebExport extends AbstractStructBase
{
    /**
     * The userName
     * Meta informations extracted from the WSDL
     * - nillable: true
     * @var string
     */
    public $userName;
    /**
     * The passwordMd5
     * Meta informations extracted from the WSDL
     * - nillable: true
     * @var string
     */
    public $passwordMd5;
    /**
     * The ecfFile
     * Meta informations extracted from the WSDL
     * - nillable: true
     * @var string
     */
    public $ecfFile;
    /**
     * Constructor method for webExport
     * @uses WebExport::setUserName()
     * @uses WebExport::setPasswordMd5()
     * @uses WebExport::setEcfFile()
     * @param string $userName
     * @param string $passwordMd5
     * @param string $ecfFile
     */
    public function __construct($userName = null, $passwordMd5 = null, $ecfFile = null)
    {
        $this
            ->setUserName($userName)
            ->setPasswordMd5($passwordMd5)
            ->setEcfFile($ecfFile);
    }
    /**
     * Get userName value
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getUserName()
    {
        return $this->userName;
    }
    /**
     * Set userName value
     * @param string $userName
     * @return \StructType\WebExport
     */
    public function setUserName($userName = null)
    {
        // validation for constraint: string
        if (!is_null($userName) && !is_string($userName)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Invalid value, please provide a string, "%s" given', gettype($userName)), __LINE__);
        }
        $this->userName = $userName;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get passwordMd5 value
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getPasswordMd5()
    {
        return $this->passwordMd5;
    }
    /**
     * Set passwordMd5 value
     * @param string $passwordMd5
     * @return \StructType\WebExport
     */
    public function setPasswordMd5($passwordMd5 = null)
    {
        // validation for constraint: string
        if (!is_null($passwordMd5) && !is_string($passwordMd5)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Invalid value, please provide a string, "%s" given', gettype($passwordMd5)), __LINE__);
        }
        $this->passwordMd5 = $passwordMd5;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get ecfFile value
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getEcfFile()
    {
        return $this->ecfFile;
    }
    /**
     * Set ecfFile value
     * @param string $ecfFile
     * @return \StructType\WebExport
     */
    public function setEcfFile($ecfFile = null)
    {
        // validation for constraint: string
        if (!is_null($ecfFile) && !is_string($ecfFile)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Invalid value, please provide a string, "%s" given', gettype($ecfFile)), __LINE__);
        }
        $this->ecfFile = $ecfFile;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Method called when an object has been exported with var_export() functions
     * It allows to return an object instantiated with the values
     * @see AbstractStructBase::__set_state()
     * @uses AbstractStructBase::__set_state()
     * @param array $array the exported values
     * @return \StructType\WebExport
     */
    public static function __set_state(array $array)
    {
        return parent::__set_state($array);
    }
    /**
     * Method returning the class name
     * @return string __CLASS__
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return __CLASS__;
    }
}
```

Heres how im trying to set the username Calling the function from Another file.

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    class Class2{
        use \StructType\webExport;
        public static function staticFunction(){
            setUserName("webservice");
        }
    }
```

Where am i going wrong? Everything works as intended if I set the password directly in the consctruct as following:

```
 public function __construct($userName = "ws", $passwordMd5 = "qwerty", $ecfFile = null)
```

Last error message:

**Fatal error: Class2 cannot use StructType\WebExport - it is not a trait in index.php on line 289**

Comment: 1) The use statement should be before the class definition. 2) Having a use statement doesn't mean you don't instantiate the object 3) the method needs called on that instantiated object.

Comment: Here are the docs http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: So you mean I should call it like this inside the class: \StructType\webExport\setUserName("webservice"); ? Doing according to you advice got me a bit further since i dont get any errors, but the username is still not set it seems like.

Comment: Do you know how to use basic PHP objects?

Comment: Yes, i do know how to use basic PHP objects. But i am still stuck at a problem I am not able to resolve by myself.

Comment: So you're aware that to call a class method, you first need to instantiate e.g. `$variable = new YourClassName`? And to call the method, you'd then use `$variable->setUserName('somevalue');`?

Answer (score 0):

you use a `use` inside class, that represent of using `Traits`, if you want to create an object of `WebExport` you can use keyword `new` to create an object of `WebExport`, example:

```
public static function staticFunction() {
    $webExport = new \StructType\WebExport();
    $webExport->setUserName('webservice');
    $webExport->setPasswordMd5('somemd5password');
    $webExport->setEcfFile(somefile)'
}
```

Traits: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Answer (score 0):

So, a couple of things here...
When you have a `use` statement **inside** a class's definition, it will be expecting a `Trait`. That use statement does need to be outside of the class's definition since you are using a Class and not a Trait here. Also, when you want to use a class, **case matters** (could just be a type-o in the OP's question). `WebExport` not `webExport`. And lastly, if you are setting an instance variable of a class, you need to have an *instance of that class* in order to set one of it's member/instance variables. I'm not sure if your Class2 is intending to extend the WebExport class, or if you're wanting to use composition and set the userName on a WebExport *property* of your new Class2. (I'm not sure how you intend your class to be structured), but I would expect any one of several possible uses...

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use \StructType\WebExport;

class Class2 {

   protected $webExportMemberVariable;

   public function __construct() {
       $this->webExportMemberVariable = new WebExport();
   }

   public function noLongerStaticFunction() {
      $this->webExportMemberVariable->setUserName("webservice");
   }
}
```

^ note in the above, that `WebExport` has capital 'W' in the use statement, and I'm calling `setUserName` on an *instance* of type `WebExport`. Doing this statically seems a little odd but still possible...

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use \StructType\WebExport;

class Class2 {

   protected static $webExportStaticVariable = new WebExport();

   public static function staticFunction() {
      self::$webExportMemberVariable->setUserName("webservice");
   }
}
```

^ doing this from a static method is a little wonky IMHO. In any case you **must** have an instance of type `\StructType\WebExport` to be setting a member variable like it seems you want to do here.